# Как JS кодом удалить пустые строки?

Tags: javascript

Для JS в переменной **arr** задан массив текста:

```
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];
```

Как удалить из него пустые строки, и чтоб он так и остался в виде массива но только без пустых строк:
[image: результат]

Answer (score 3):

C помощью **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** например

```js
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];

let filteredArr = arr.filter(el => el.trim() !== '');

console.log(filteredArr)
```

---

через `reduce`

```js
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];

let filteredArr = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.trim() !== '')
    acc.push(el);
    
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredArr)
```

---

Просто `for..of`

```js
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];

filteredArr = [];

for (el of arr) {
    if (el.trim() !== '')
        filteredArr.push(el);
}


console.log(filteredArr)
```

---

Можно изменить тот же самый массив

```js
let arr = ["When I consider every thing that grows",
"",
"Holds in perfection but a little moment,",
"",
"That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows",
"",
"Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;"];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (arr[i].trim() === '')
        arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: В последнем алгоритме чисто для общего случая, будет надёжнее написать `i >= 0` в условии цикла. Иначе первый элемент не будет удалён, если он будет пустым :)

Comment: Да, исправил)))